# Does Australia have one of the Highest levels of temporary employment in the OECD?

Tags: australia, employment

There is a post being shared around by [Australian Unions](https://www.australianunions.org.au/) that claims Australia has one highest level of temporary employment in the OECD. The image has a list of 15 countries where the [OECD](https://www.oecd.org/about/membersandpartners/list-oecd-member-countries.htm) has approximately 30 nations.

[image]

Is the statement made about employment fair or misleading?

Comment: I wonder whether Germany is sixth from left to avoid colliding with the very mathematically valid trend line they have.

Comment: A deleted answer posted concerns that the definition of “temporary” may vary from country to country.

Comment: Without a (consistent) definition of "temporary employment" the statement is meaningless.

Comment: Indeed, the definition of temporary employment may vary, but the image includes a [citation to a 2004 paper](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/10301763.2004.10669311) that carefully examines this question before comparing the figures.

Comment: The statistics for Germany is incorrect which makes the whole data untrustable. According to *Statistisches Bundesamt* there were 37040 thousand employed people in Germany in 2016 ([pdf](https://www.destatis.de/DE/Publikationen/Thematisch/Arbeitsmarkt/Erwerbstaetige/ErwerbsbeteiligungBevoelkung2010410167004.pdf?__blob=publicationFile), 8 megabyte, page 78). 4856 thousand of them temporarily employed. Even if we remove people who are temporarily employed because being in education (1874 thousand), the level of temporarily employed would be about 8% which is more than ca.5% shown in the graph.

Comment: No https://data.oecd.org/chart/5bnr

Comment: (But Australian workers are up against the wall and close to burning down the rich out of frustration, it is hard for some and impossible for all to be employed, there are 200,000 vacancies and 800,000 people looking for work) https://www.businessinsider.com.au/australia-unemployment-population-growth-jobs-wages-2018-5  http://www.abs.gov.au/ausstats/abs@.nsf/mf/6354.0